# How to use progress bar in wpf without multithreading?

Tags: c#, wpf, task, progress-bar, backgroundworker

Help please.

I want to see the progress bar change with the IsIndeterminate= true property while reading from the database.

I know that I can use Task and BackgroundWorker to create another thread. But for me, it is very important that I do not leave the method in which the long-term operation takes place until it is finished. What can be done in this case?

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Why is it so important you don't leave this method? Usually, the time is taken up between making a database call and getting the data back. Making your method async and awaiting a task is the simple way to handle that. There are pre built tasks you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0 or https://dapper-tutorial.net/async

Answer (score 8):

You can't. The UI thread needs to run to display the change to the progress bar, at the same time as your method is running.

Run your method in a background thread, but disable everything in the window before you start so the user can't change anything, and set the mouse pointer to an hourglass so they don't try.

Use try/catch/finally to re-enable everything at the end and reset the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 3):

After awaiting a Task, execution returns to the method where you started the Task. This is perhaps all you need, as the method isn't actually "left".

Here is a sample Button Click event handler that disables itself before awaiting an awaitable method call (e.g. some long running operation), and that enables itself again when the call has completed:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.IsEnabled = false;

    await SomethingAsync();

    button.IsEnabled = true;
}

private Task SomethingAsync()
{
    // ...
}
```